# Deleting all nodes of a particular number in a linked list

Tags: c++, list, linked-list, singly-linked-list

As part of a linked list, one of the functions I'm required to write is a function that searches the entire list for all nodes whose data value is a particular number and delete all of them.

For example, in a list of `1, 3, 3, 3, 7, 9`, it would delete all of the `3`s and change the list to `1, 7, 9,`

I have a noted version of the function in my program currently where I tried several different... things (they're noted inside of the block), and none of them worked.

```
    void linkedlist::deletenode(int n){
        while (first != NULL){
            linknode *temp = new linknode;
            temp = first;
            //first = temp -> next
            //first = first -> next
            if (temp -> data == n){
               //first = temp -> next
               delete temp;
            }
            //first = first -> next;
        }
    }
```

I scrapped it entirely and decided to rewrite the function entirely. Here's what it looks like.

```
void linkedlist::deletenode(int n){
do{
linknode *temp= new linknode;
temp=first;
first=first->next;
if (temp -> data == n){
delete temp;

}

} while (first -> next != NULL);
```

}

The issue I'm having is, instead of deleting all nodes of a particular number, it deletes all of the numbers in the list except the last one.

For example, if the list is:

```
2, 4, 2, 6, 7, 528,
```

And `n = 2`, the list just goes to `528`.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Below is the class definition.

```
    class linkedlist{ //begin class definition
public:

    bool empty;
    linknode *first;

    linkedlist(){
        empty = true; first = NULL;

    }

    void createfirst(int); //done
    void addbeginning(int); //done
    void append(int); //done
    void printlist(); //done
    void deletenode(int);
    void insertlist(int);
    void clearlist(); //done 

};
```

Comment: Show the list definition.

Comment: Take a pencil, an eraser and a paper, draw your list *first -> 2 -> 4 -> 2 -> 6 -> 7 -> 528* and try to execute your function step by step, drawing result of each step. You reach great experience in comparison with a ready answer.

Comment: What is strange here is that you modify "first" even if it should not be (`first=first->next;` should only happen conditionally to `if (temp -> data == n)`)

Comment: And using good-old @S.M. method you would find this quite quickly by yourself.

Comment: @BenjaminBarrois You'll have to excuse my ignorance, but when I do this by hand, if I don't progress "first" on every loop, as soon as the if statement is false, the loop infinitely checks the same number. The very first statement "temp = first" will always set temp equal to the first node because "first" only progresses if the if statement is true.

Comment: @Yvain The problem is mostly that you should not use `first` data member to browse your linked list, this is destructive.

Comment: @BenjaminBarrois Can you explain why you suggest not using "first" to browse a linked list? I hate to be a bother but I'm really much more focused on learning how this works than completing my assignment.

Comment: The problem is that by using ̀first` data member to browse your list, you use the first node of your list to successively point to the others. At the end, your node n°1 points to the last one and the rest of your linked list is definitely lost, which is exactly the result you get (528). You should create a new temporary node to browse the others.

Comment: @Yvain Please read at last my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your function implementation in any case is wrong at least because it changes the data member `first` in each iteration of the loop (so after exiting the function the data member will not point to the first node of the list as it occurred in case of the list example 2, 4, 2, 6, 7, 528, provided by you) and there is a memory leak due to the redundant use of the new operator.

```
linknode *temp = new linknode;
```

The function can look the following way

```
void linkedlist::deletenode( int data )
{
    for ( linknode **current = &first; *current; )
    {
        if ( *current )->data == data )
        {
            linknode *tmp = *current;
            *current = ( *current )->next;
            delete tmp;
        }
        else
        {
            current = &( *current )->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Take into account that these data members

```
public:

    bool empty;
    linknode *first;
```

should be declared as **private**. Otherwise your list is unsafe.

Comment: I was just wondering why you used a double pointer instead of a single pointer? Just personal preference?

Comment: If I don't declare it public, I thought I would not be able to access it in other functions. Thanks for you answer.

Comment: @Yvain You could wirte for example a constant function that reports whether the list is empty.

Comment: @Daniel It allows to use a general approach instead of analysing partial cases.

Comment: @Daniel And it is not a personal preference. It is a sign of the level of the qualification.:)